# What does the colon mean in this set-builder notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The instructions say: "Let D be a relation on the natural numbers (N) defined by D = { (m,n) : m | n }"

How does one read this set-builder notation? I don't remember seeing any colons like this in lecture.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is off-topic for stackoverflow, and belongs on Mathematics.SE instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 4):

The colon means "*such that*". The set D is the set of all ordered pairs (m,n) *such that* m divides n.